# Converting dataframe containing columns data type to json showing some encoded variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe(df):

```
Index           col1    col2      col3
data_type       object  float64   float64
record_count    20      20        30
Percentage      10      8         5
```

When I am converting this dataframe into `json`, i got the below json file:

```
  df.to_json()

    "col1": {
        "data_type": {
            "alignment": 8,
            "byteorder": "=",
            "descr": [
                [
                    "",
                    "<f8"
                ]
            ],
            "flags": 0,
            "isalignedstruct": false,
            "isnative": true,
            "kind": "o",
            "name": "object",
            "num": 12,
            "str": "<f8"
        }
        "record_count": 20,
        "Percentage"  :10
}
       "col2": {
        "data_type": {
            "alignment": 8,
            "byteorder": "=",
            "descr": [
                [
                    "",
                    "<f8"
                ]
            ],
            "flags": 0,
            "isalignedstruct": false,
            "isnative": true,
            "kind": "f",
            "name": "float64",
            "num": 12,
            "str": "<f8"
        }
        "record_count": 20,
        "Percentage"  :8
},
    "col3": {
        "data_type": {
            "alignment": 8,
            "byteorder": "=",
            "descr": [
                [
                    "",
                    "<f8"
                ]
            ],
            "flags": 0,
            "isalignedstruct": false,
            "isnative": true,
            "kind": "f",
            "name": "float64",
            "num": 12,
            "str": "<f8"
        }
        "record_count": 30,
        "Percentage"  :5
}
```

I want to extract only data_type like below:

```
    "col1": {
                "data_type": "float64",
                "record_count":'20',
                "Percentage" : 10
                }
```

I have similar rows with different integer as well as string values, I am able to extract them as it is, but for data_type I am getting unknown characters after converting to json.

Comment: `df.applymap(type).to_json()`?

Comment: @ansev- This does not worked for me.